# What is the limit of convergence of the geometric series?

Tags: limits, geometric-series

I have a function of geometric series
\begin{equation}
f(\lambda,x) = \frac{1-\lambda^{x+1}}{1-\lambda^x},
\end{equation}
where $|\lambda|<1$ and $x\in Z^+$.

For a fixed $x$, i.e. $x=500$, $f(\lambda,x)$ will start from 1 and converge to 1.002, as $\lambda$ moves towards $1$.

I am wondering, is it possible to find a closed-form solution as a function of $x$ to determine $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow 1} f(\lambda,x)$?

P.S. it seems that $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow 1} f(\lambda,x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}$, but why?

Comment: Apply L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: Yes, of course! Thank you very much, I completely forgot the L'Hopital's Rule.